# How can I get the ID/Name of an entry using datastore

Tags: java, google-app-engine, gwt, google-cloud-datastore, jdo

When I look under http://localhost:8888/_ah/admin/ I can see that every entry in datastore has an ID/Name field. I also know that I can get objects with this id using `persistenceManager.getObject(clazz, id);`

Is it possible to mark some attribute to use the value of this field? So that when requestion object `A` I could easily access it's ID/Name?

**Note**: I am not using the Key object because it gave me trouble using the same object in client and server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to add `@Extension` to my ID attribute (key="gae.pk-id")

```
@Persistent
@Extension(vendorName="datanucleus", key="gae.pk-id", value="true")
private Long keyId;
```